# Laravel Eloquent: whereHas on relationship involving multiple tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on a Laravel project. I am using Eloquent to query data from the database.

I have the following models

Donation.php

```
class Donation extends Model
{
    public function donator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Model
{
   public function charities()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Charity::class);
   }
}
```

Charity.php

```
class Charity extends Model
{
   public function donators()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
   }
}
```

I am writing a query on Donation model class and I am trying to query something like this. The query is just abstraction.

```
Donation::whereHas('donator.charities', function($query) {
     $query->whereIn('charities.id', [ 1,2,3,4 ])
})
```

As you can see in the whereHas, I am applying the where clause on charities of donator. Is it possible to do that? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this would be the answer of your question.

```
Donation::whereHas('donator',function($query){
  $query->whereHas('charities',function($query){
     $query->whereIn('id',[1,2,3,4]);
  })
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am after.